# Changing the QWidgetAction style in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

I am having troubles with customizing menu items with the class QWidgetAction. I create my own QWidget and set it as the default widget of the QWidgetAction. Then I add the QWidgetAction to the Menu:

```
QMenu menu = new QMenu(this);
QCustomWidget* widget = new QCustomWdiget(this);  // inherits from QWidget
QCustomAction* action = new QCustomAction(this);  // Inherits from QWidgetAction
action->setDefaultWidget(widget);
menu->addAction(action);
```

The custom action is added to the Menu but the normal functions such as navigating with the arrows, focusing the elements on hover etc. are not available. I just get a widget that does not inherit the behaviour of a normal menu item. I tried to set the sytlesheet of my customwidget. but setting the same colors, background gradients, borders, font type, font size etc of the normal action is too much work and unaccurate. Is there any way to inherit the style and/or behaviour of the standard action item?

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution to make **hover** work:

```
void QCustomWidget::enterEvent(QEvent* e)
{
  emit entered();
}

void QCustomAction::onWidgetEntered()
{
    if (QMenu* menu = qobject_cast<QMenu*>(sender()->parent()))
    {
        menu->setActiveAction(this);
    }
}

// when you created both:

connect(customWidget, SIGNAL(entered()), customAction, SLOT(onWidgetEntered()));
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ezee
I tried your way,but it did't take effect.
I used enterEvent and leaveEvent to realize the hover effect;
When mouse moved on to the action,the code would run into the enterEvent,but the stylesheet didn't take effect.

But I found another way to realize my feature.What I want to do is just change the icon when the mouse hovers the action,I can use the QIcon::addIcon(QIcon::hover,XXXXX).In this way,I can change the hover-icon easily.